# Bluetooth on RPi Zero W does't work

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I have a problem and, although I have searched the solution for many parts and for three days, I can not solve it so I come to ask for help.

The problem: I recently bought a glittering Raspberry Pi Zero W, an Essentials Kit from The Pi Hut (www.ThePiHut.com), and prove it is a Rpi Zero W as on the back of the circuit says "[i]Raspberry Pi Zero W v1. 1[/i] "and has the antenna that looks like a small horn.

My problem is with the Bluetooth of the Zero W, I do not manage to make it work, I do not even get the Rpi to recognize it.

I've spent three days researching and following the steps of the guides:

1 - Install *Raspbian Jessie Lite* (via "burn" the image on the microSD) because it was the repo I had available (I live in Cuba, access to the internet makes it difficult and expensive).

2 - Enter the microSD and modify the **cmdline.txt** and the **config.txt** to be able to connect via SSH using the OTG port of the Rpi Zero.

3 - A "little" (delayed) actualization:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dis-upgrade
```

4 - Restart the RPi

5 - Installation of the necessary packages:

```
apt-get install -y bluetooth pi-bluetooth bluez bluez-firmware
```

*(and some other necessary packages)*

6 - Another reboot

7 - Now supposedly I should already recognize the bluetooth, however:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

And he tells me that the service is running, however:

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth
```

It tells me that the service is up, but there is nothing pointing out that the hci0 interface (which is supposed to be the bluetooth interface) is working

8 - Attempt:

```
bluetoothctl
agent on (Agent is on)
power on (Do not such device)
```

Also:

```
hciconfig dev (Can not get device info: No such device)
hcitool lescan (Could not open device: No such device)
```

Also:
I installed rfkill because some guides said that if you used the rfkill to "turn off" and "turn on" the interface might have a solution. But:

```
rfkill list
```

And the answer to that is empty...It's as if I did not recognize any bluetooth device

9 - In some post law that was the Bluez that was not well installed, so I downloaded it (the version bluez-5.43.tar) and compile it in the RPI Zero W (the process takes almost 2 hours), and when I finish, The same thing happens to me! (Jessie did not let me compile it, but Stretch did).

Well, after much work I got the Stretch repository and I follow the steps from 1 to 9 again, but continue saying the same thing, only in Stretch I can compile the Bluez.

Someone can help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are you intending to connect to with Raspbian Lite and Bluetooth?

Comment: I want to connect the Wiimote from Nintendo, but I don't think that the "what" matters, I want to know how can I turn ON my Bluetooth.

Comment: Ah - now i can try it myself - I didn't think of connecting to a wiimote.

Comment: Using a fresh image of Raspbian Stretch with Desktop 2017-09-07, fully updated, on my Pi Zero W. I just successfully connected to a wiimote using the bluetooth gui. I didn't need to install anything.

Comment: @CoderMike Sorry for the late...I just download the Stretch Lite, I'll tested when I go home...let me download also the image with Desktop. Thanks, Iet you know the results.